# ANTLR4 no viable alternative at input 'do { return' error?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

This ANTLR4 parser grammar errors a 'no viable alternative' error when I try to parse an input. The only rules I know of that matches the part of the input with the error are the rules 'retblock_expr' and 'block_expr'. I have put 'retblock_expr' infront of 'block_expr' and put 'non_assign_expr' infront of 'retblock_expr' but it still throws the error.

input:

> print(do { return a[3] })

full error:

> line 1:11 no viable alternative at input '(do { return'

parser grammar:

```
parser grammar TestP;
options { tokenVocab=Test; }
program: (  (   block_expr | retblock_expr  ) ( wsp (   block_expr | retblock_expr  ) wsp   )* wsp  )? EOF;
retblock_expr
    : isglobal DEF wsp fcreatable wsp fcall wsp (   DO wsp  )? (    LBC wsp block_expr wsp RBC | block_expr wsp END ) #FuncBlockA
    | FUNC wsp fcall wsp (  DO wsp  )? (    LBC wsp block_expr wsp RBC | block_expr wsp END ) #CFuncBlockA
    | LAMBDA wsp fcall wsp (    DO wsp  )? (    LBC wsp block_expr wsp RBC | block_expr wsp END ) #LambdaBlockA
    | SWITCH wsp atompar_option wsp (   DO wsp  )? (    LBC wsp (CASE wsp atompar_option wsp (  block_expr wsp END | LBC wsp block_expr wsp RBC )   )* (    DEFAULT wsp atompar_option wsp (    block_expr wsp END | LBC wsp block_expr wsp RBC )   )? wsp RBC | (CASE wsp atompar_option wsp ( block_expr wsp END | LBC wsp block_expr wsp RBC )   )* (    DEFAULT wsp atompar_option wsp (    block_expr wsp END | LBC wsp block_expr wsp RBC )   )? wsp END  ) #SwitchBlockA
    | DO wsp (  LBC wsp block_expr wsp RBC | block_expr wsp END ) #DoBlockA
;
non_assign_expr
    : ( iterable (  (   DOT | SUP | SIB ) iterable  )+ | index  ) #AccessExpr
    | ( call | datat | LPR non_assign_expr RPR | LBC non_assign_expr RBC | LBR non_assign_expr RBR  ) #BracketsExpr
    | ( STR | KUN   )+ indexable #UnpackExpr
    | <assoc=right>  non_assign_expr (  wsp POW wsp non_assign_expr )+ #PowExpr
    | non_assign_expr ( wsp (   INC | DEC   ) wsp non_assign_expr | INC | DEC   )+ #CrementExpr
    | ( PLS | MNS | BNT | EXC | LEN | NOT   )+ non_assign_expr #UnaryExpr
    | non_assign_expr EXC+ #FactExpr
    | non_assign_expr ( wsp (   STR | DIV | PER | FDV | CDV ) wsp non_assign_expr | PER )+ # AdvExpr
    | non_assign_expr ( wsp (   PLS | MNS   ) wsp non_assign_expr   )+ #BasicExpr
    | non_assign_expr ( wsp CON wsp non_assign_expr )+ #ConcatExpr
    | non_assign_expr ( wsp (   BLS | BRS   ) wsp non_assign_expr   )+ #ShiftExpr
    | non_assign_expr ( wsp (   LET | LTE | GRT | GTE   ) wsp non_assign_expr   )+ #CompareExpr
    | non_assign_expr ( wsp (   EQL | IS | NEQ | IS wsp NOT ) wsp non_assign_expr   )+ #EqualExpr
    | non_assign_expr ( wsp BND wsp non_assign_expr )+ #BitAnd
    | non_assign_expr ( wsp BXR wsp non_assign_expr )+ #BitXor
    | non_assign_expr ( wsp BOR wsp non_assign_expr )+ #BitOr
    | <assoc=right> non_assign_expr (   wsp (   AND | TND   ) wsp non_assign_expr wsp ( OR | TOR    ) wsp non_assign_expr   )+ #Ternary
    | non_assign_expr ( wsp (   NND | AND   ) wsp non_assign_expr   )+ #AndExpr
    | non_assign_expr ( wsp (   NXR | XOR   ) wsp non_assign_expr   )+ #XorExpr
    | non_assign_expr ( wsp (   NOR | OR    ) wsp non_assign_expr   )+ #OrExpr
    | retblock_expr #RBlockA
    | typet LPR non_assign_expr RPR #TypeCastA
    | atom #AtomNAE
;
block_expr
    : IF wsp non_assign_expr wsp (  (   THEN wsp block_expr | LBC wsp block_expr wsp RBC    ) wsp ( (   ELIF wsp non_assign_expr wsp THEN wsp block_expr | ELIF wsp non_assign_expr wsp LBC wsp block_expr wsp RBC  )* ELSE wsp (   block_expr wsp END | LBC wsp block_expr wsp RBC ) | (   ELIF wsp non_assign_expr wsp THEN wsp block_expr | ELIF wsp non_assign_expr wsp LBC wsp block_expr wsp RBC  )*? (   ELIF wsp non_assign_expr wsp THEN wsp block_expr wsp END | ELIF wsp non_assign_expr wsp LBC wsp block_expr wsp RBC  )   ) | (   THEN wsp block_expr wsp END | LBC wsp block_expr wsp RBC    )   ) #IfBlock
    | TRY wsp ( block_expr wsp (    EXCEPT (LPR wsp IDN wsp RPR)? wsp (  (  (DO wsp)? LBC wsp block_expr wsp RBC | DO wsp block_expr wsp END | block_expr   ) wsp   )? FINALLY wsp (    block_expr wsp END | LBC wsp block_expr wsp RBC ) | EXCEPT (LPR wsp IDN wsp RPR)? wsp ( block_expr wsp END | LBC wsp block_expr wsp RBC )   ) | (   block_expr wsp END | LBC wsp block_expr wsp RBC )   ) #DebugBlock
    | FOR wsp av_var wsp TOR wsp av_inc wsp CMA wsp av_inc wsp (    CMA wsp av_inc wsp  )? (    DO wsp  )? (    LBC wsp block_expr wsp RBC | block_expr wsp END ) #RangeBlock
    | FOR wsp av_var wsp CMA wsp non_assign_expr wsp CMA wsp non_assign_expr wsp CMA wsp non_assign_expr wsp (  DO wsp  )? (    LBC wsp block_expr wsp RBC | block_expr wsp END ) #ActionBlock
    | FOR wsp IDN wsp ( TOR wsp non_assign_expr )? (    wsp CMA wsp (   IDN wsp (   TOR wsp non_assign_expr )?  )? (    wsp CMA wsp IDN wsp TOR wsp non_assign_expr )*  )? IN wsp iterable wsp (    DO wsp  )? (    LBC wsp block_expr wsp RBC | block_expr wsp END ) #IterationBlock
    | ( WHILE wsp non_assign_expr wsp ( DO wsp  )? (    LBC wsp block_expr wsp RBC | block_expr wsp END ) | DO wsp (    LBC wsp block_expr wsp RBC | block_expr ) wsp WHILE wsp non_assign_expr ) #WhileBlock
    | ( (   DO | REPEAT ) wsp ( LBC wsp block_expr wsp RBC | block_expr ) wsp UNTIL wsp non_assign_expr | UNTIL wsp non_assign_expr wsp (   DO | REPEAT ) ( LBC wsp block_expr wsp RBC | block_expr wsp END )   ) #RepeatBlock
    | isglobal DEF wsp fcreatable wsp fcall wsp (   DO wsp  )? (    LBC wsp block_expr wsp RBC | block_expr wsp END ) #FuncBlock
    | FUNC wsp fcall wsp (  DO wsp  )? (    LBC wsp block_expr wsp RBC | block_expr wsp END ) #CFuncBlock
    | LAMBDA wsp fcall wsp (    DO wsp  )? (    LBC wsp block_expr wsp RBC | block_expr wsp END ) #LambdaBlock
    | SWITCH wsp atompar_option wsp (   DO wsp  )? (    LBC wsp (CASE wsp atompar_option wsp (  block_expr wsp END | LBC wsp block_expr wsp RBC )   )* (    DEFAULT wsp atompar_option wsp (    block_expr wsp END | LBC wsp block_expr wsp RBC )   )? wsp RBC | (CASE wsp atompar_option wsp ( block_expr wsp END | LBC wsp block_expr wsp RBC )   )* (    DEFAULT wsp atompar_option wsp (    block_expr wsp END | LBC wsp block_expr wsp RBC )   )? wsp END  ) #SwitchBlock
    | DO wsp (  LBC wsp block_expr wsp RBC | block_expr wsp END ) #DoBlock
    | LPR block_expr RPR #EnclosedBlockA
    | LBC block_expr RBC #EnclosedBlockB
    | block #OpenBlock
;
atompar_option
    : LPR wsp atom wsp RPR
    | atom
;
isglobal: ( GLOBAL wsp  )?;
block: (    stat+ wsp (PASS | retstat)* )+ | PASS;
stat
    : expression+ wsp SMC*
    | expression* wsp SMC+
;
retstat: RETURN wsp non_assign_expr;
expression
    : <assoc=right> isglobal var_list ( wsp aop wsp expression  )+ #AssignExpr
    | exp_list #ExpListA
    | non_assign_expr #NonAssign
    | atom #AtomEXPR
    | IVC #InvalidCharacter
;
literal
    : strt
    | num
;
datat
    : listd
    | dictd
    | setd
    | tupled
;
wsp: WSP*;
listd
    : LBR wsp exp_list wsp RBR
    | EML
;
dictd
    : LBC wsp kvpair wsp
    (
        CMA
        wsp
        kvpair
        wsp
    )*
    RBC
;
setd
    : LBC wsp exp_list wsp RBC
    | EMS
;
indexable
    : ( dictd | IDN | ( (   datat | IDN | strt  )   ) LBR non_assign_expr RBR | (   datat | IDN | strt  ) ( (   DOT | SUP | SIB ) ( datat | IDN | strt  )   )+  ) fcall
    | ( (   datat | IDN | strt  )   ) LBR non_assign_expr RBR
    | ( datat | IDN | strt  ) ( (   DOT | SUP | SIB ) ( datat | IDN | strt  )   )+
    | IDN
    | datat
;
iterable
    : indexable
    | strt
;
numidn
    : num
    | IDN
;
av_numidn
    : numidn
    | av_var
;
av_inc
    : av_numidn
    | call
;
tupled: LPR wsp (exp_list | CMA) wsp RPR;
kvpair: non_assign_expr wsp TOR wsp non_assign_expr;
index
    : ( iterable    ) LBR non_assign_expr RBR
    | iterable (    (   DOT | SUP | SIB ) iterable  )+
;
var_list: ( typet wsp   )? av_var ( wsp CMA wsp (   typet wsp   )? var_list)*;
av_var
    : IDN
    | index
;
exp_list: non_assign_expr (wsp CMA wsp non_assign_expr)*;
atom
    : num
    | av_var
    | strt
    | typet
    | ckw
    | val
    | datat
;
aop
    : A_FDV // '//='
    | A_CDV // '*/='
    | A_NOR // '||='
    | A_FAC // '=!='
    | A_LTE // '=<='
    | A_GTE // '=>='
    | A_EQL // '==='
    | A_NEQ // '!=='
    | A_CON // '..='
    | A_NXR // '$$='
    | A_BRS // '>>='
    | A_NND // '&&='
    | A_BLS // '<<='
    | A_DCL // '::='
    | A_CLD // ':.='
    | A_KUN // '=**'
    | A_VUN // '=*'
    | A_DOT // '.='
    | A_POW // '^='
    | A_NOT // '=!'
    | A_BNT // '=~'
    | A_LEN // '=#'
    | A_PER // '=%'
    | A_MUL // '*='
    | A_DIV // '/='
    | A_MOD // '%='
    | A_ADD // '+='
    | A_SUB // '-='
    | A_LET // '=<'
    | A_GRT // '=>'
    | A_BND // '&='
    | A_BXR // '$='
    | A_BOR // '|='
    | A_TND // '?='
    | A_TOR // ':='
    | A_NML // '='
;
num
    : exponential
    | non_exponential
;
exponential
    : PXI
    | DXI
    | PXF
    | DXF
    | PXB
    | DXB
    | PXD
    | DXD
    | PXP
    | DXP
    | PRX
    | DEX
;
non_exponential
    : IMG
    | FLT
    | DBL
    | DCM
    | PRC
    | INT
;
fcreatable
    : dictd
    | av_var
;
callablets
    : fcreatable
    | retblock_expr
    | ckw
;
fcall
    : CLP
    | LPR arg_list RPR
;
call: callablets fcall;
arg_list: arg_type (    wsp CMA wsp arg_type    )*;
arg_type
    : u_var_list wsp aop wsp u_exp_list
    | unkeyed_var
;
unkeyed_var
    : LPR var_list RPR
    | LBR var_list RBR
    | LBC var_list RBC
    | var_list
;
u_var_list: unkeyed_var (   wsp aop wsp u_var_list  )*;
u_exp_list: unkeyed_exp (   wsp CMA wsp unkeyed_exp )*;
unkeyed_exp
    : tupled
    | listd
    | setd
    | non_assign_expr
;
litidn
    : literal
    | IDN
;
typecast: typet LPR non_assign_expr RPR;
strt
    : multi_line
    | single_line
    | char_string
;
multi_line
    : SMT
    | USM
    | NMT
    | UNM
;
single_line
    : SST
    | USS
    | NST
    | UNS
    | NAS
;
char_string
    : SCH
    | USC
    | NCH
    | UNC
    | NAC
;
typet
    : STRT
    | INTT
    | NUMT
    | DECIMALT
    | FLOATT
    | DOUBLET
    | PRECISET
    | EXPNT
    | CHART
    | IMAGT
    | REALT
    | HEXTY
    | BINTY
    | OCTTY
    | LISTD
    | SETD
    | DICTD
    | TUPLED
    | TYPET
    | BOOLT
;

bks_or_WSP
    : WSP
    | BKS
    | SPC
;
emd
    : EML
    | EMS
;
sep
    : SMC
    | CMA
    | TOR
;

kwr
    : WHILE
    | FOR
    | DO
    | DEL
    | NEW
    | IMPORT
    | EXPORT
    | DEF
    | END
    | GLOBAL
    | BREAK
    | CONTINUE
    | NOT
    | AND
    | OR
    | IN
    | CASE
    | DEFAULT
    | RETURN
    | TRY
    | EXCEPT
    | FINALLY
    | ELIF
    | IF
    | ELSE
    | AS
    | CONST
    | REPEAT
    | UNTIL
    | THEN
    | GOTO
    | LABEL
    | USING
    | PUBLIC
    | PROTECTED
    | PRIVATE
    | SELF
    | FROM
    | XOR
    | IMAGT
    | REALT
    | WHERE
    | PASS
    | G_G
    | L_L
    | MAP
    | IS
;
ckw
    : OPN
    | OUT
    | OUTF
    | PRINT
    | PRINTF
    | LAMBDA
    | FUNC
    | ERR
    | ERRF
    | ASSERT
    | ASSERTF
    | FORMAT
    | SWITCH
    | ABS
    | ASCII
    | CALLABLE
    | CHR
    | DIR
    | EVAL
    | EXEC
    | FILTER
    | GET
    | HASH
    | ID
    | INST
    | SUB
    | SUPER
    | MAX
    | MIN
    | OBJ
    | ORD
    | POWF
    | REV
    | REPR
    | ROUND
    | FLOOR
    | CEIL
    | MUL
    | SORT
    | ADD
    | ZIP
    | WAIT
    | SECS
    | MILS
    | BENCHMARK
;

val
    : RMH // 'inf'
    | IMH // 'infi'
    | NAN // 'nan'
    | IND // 'ind'
    | UND // 'und'
    | NIL // 'nil'
    | NON // 'none'
    | TRU // 'true'
    | FLS // 'false'
;

opr
    : NND // '&&'
    | NXR // '$$'
    | NOR // '||'
    | CLP // '()'
    | SUP // '::'
    | SIB // ':.'
    | KUN // '**'
    | INC // '++'
    | DEC // '+-'
    | FDV // '//'
    | CDV // '* /'
    | CON // '..'
    | BLS // '<<'
    | BRS // '>>'
    | LTE // '<='
    | GTE // '>='
    | EQL // '=='
    | NEQ // '!='
    | LPR // '('
    | RPR // ')'
    | LBR // '['
    | RBR // ']'
    | LBC // '{'
    | RBC // '}'
    | STR // '*'
    | POW // '^'
    | PLS // '+'
    | MNS // '-'
    | BNT // '~'
    | EXC // '!'
    | LEN // '#'
    | PER // '%'
    | DIV // '/'
    | LET // '<'
    | GRT // '>'
    | BND // '&'
    | BXR // '$'
    | BOR // '|'
    | TND // '?'
    | TOR // ':'
    | DOT // '.'
;

inl
    : strt
    | num
    | ckw
    | kwr
    | val
    | IDN
    | bks_or_WSP
    | sep
    | emd
    | aop
    | opr
    | typet
    | IVC
;
```

Comment: I've provided an answer to this specific issue.  That said, and I mean this in the best possible way,  you're clearly in over your head with this grammar.  I want to see you succeed, and your best possible path to success in this project is to backup, start simple, and build from there (really learning ANTLR along the way).  There are so many "red flags" in this grammar that I can't begin to enumerate them.  (the "kwh" rule that appears to be a rule that matches keywords, is a glaring example.  This is just NOT how keywords are used in ANTLR.).

Comment: There are a lot of problems here. 1) You don't give your lexer grammar. 2) Please use standard names for the lexer and parser: 1st lines should be `lexer grammar TestLexer;` in TestLexer.g4; `parser grammar TestParser;` in TestParser.g4. 3) Why are you using WSP in the parser? Few ever do that unless you know what you are doing. Simplify your parser grammar by removing every `wsp` and adding WSP: [ \n\r] -> skip;` to your lexer grammar

Comment: @kaby76 1. the lexer is okay, it lexes fine. 2. i'll probably do that. 3. i don't remember what kind of statement it is, but it has to be separated by whitespaces or else the statement shouldn't match.

Comment: What kaby76 (most probably) means that by not providing the lexer grammar, people cannot reproduce the error you mentioned.

Comment: `wsp` is nullable (derives the empty string). So the applied occurrences in all parser rules do not force spaces surround a statement, as you say you want. If that is what you want, then make `wsp: WSP+;` or make it a semantic predicate in lexer. The grammar should be simplified.

Comment: IMO, the better option would be to just add semantic predicates to the lexer. Then you can remove the `wsp` in the parser rules and simplify the grammar enormously. When you go to write a spec for your language, add prose on the intertoken requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `PRINT` token can only be matched by the `blk_expr` rule through this path:

[image]

There is no path for `retblock_expr` to recognize anything that begins with the `PRINT` token.

As a result, it will not matter which order you have `elk_expr` or `retblock_expr`.

There is no parser rule in your grammar that will match a `PRINT` token followed by a `LPR` token.  a `block_expr` is matched by the `program` rule, and it only matches (ignoring wsp) `block_expr` or `retblock_expr`.  Neither of these have alternatives that begin with an `LPR` token, so ANTLR can't match that token.

`print(...)` would normally be matched as a function call expression that accepts 0 or more comma-separated parameters.  You have no sure rule/alternative defined.  (I'd *guess* that it should be an alternative on either `retblock_expr` or `block_expr`

That's the *immediate* cause of this error.  ANTLR really does not have any rule/alternative that can accept a `LPR` token in this position.

Comment: I found the parser rule which causes the error by adding an error listener. The offending text was 'return' (`RETURN`), which narrowed it down to the `block` parser rule, since I required a `stat` expression before a `retstat` one, therefore causing an error. I fixed it now, thanks for the graph which helped me solve the error.